# Tensor scalar field - Laplacian, rot and multiplying by vector in cartesian and spherical coordinates

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I got a serious problem with an exercise I got on my tensor course.

I was given the following scalar field (in 3 dimensional physical space):
$$ \phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}a^2(\frac{r^2(x)}{3a^2}-1)$$
$$ r(x) = |x|, |x| > a$$
We are talking about tensor field, so the |x| is actually not a single coordinate, but the length, more like (in cartesian): $|x| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$, where the $x_i$ are the coordinates.

I have to calculate, both in cartesian and spherical coordinates, the values of:
$F(x)=\nabla^2 \phi(x)$, $rot(\nabla \phi(x))$ and $F(x) \cdot a$, where $a$ is a vector of length a.

I know that in case of tensor derivative theory:
$$\nabla\phi = \frac{\delta\phi}{\delta x_1}\overline{e_1} + \frac{\delta\phi}{\delta x_2}\overline{e_2} + \frac{\delta\phi}{\delta x_3}\overline{e_3}$$
And one more time you get (in general form):
$$\nabla(\nabla\phi) = \frac{\delta^2\phi}{\delta x_i\delta x_j}\overline{e_i}\otimes\overline{e_j}$$
but I have no idea how can I go forward with this. I tried just pluggin the $r(x)$ value in (then I get $ \phi(x_1, x_2, x_3)=\frac{1}{2}a^2(\frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}{3a^2}-1)$). I can easily calculate derivatives on $x_1, x_2, x_3$ from this, but it seems too easy or just too stupid to be correct.

Any help would be heavily appreciated.

EDIT:
There are my attempts of solving it "the too easy way" (which is the right way apparently):
$$ \phi(x)=\frac{1}{2}a^2(\frac{r^2(x)}{3a^2}-1)=\frac{r^2(x)}{6} - \frac{1}{2}a^2$$
Using that $|x| = \sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$:
$$\phi(x_1, x_2, x_3) = \frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}a^2$$
(I assume I can omit the absolute value because of the $|x| > a$ condition)
Then calculating the first $\nabla$:
$$\nabla\phi = [\frac{x_1}{3}, \frac{x_2}{3}, \frac{x_3}{3}]$$
Second one:
$$F(x) = \nabla(\nabla\phi) = \begin {bmatrix}
\frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0\\
0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3}\begin {bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{1}{3}I$$
Rotation (or $curl$) indeed equals 0.

In this case the multiplication by vector $\overline{a} = [a_1, a_2, a_3]$:
$$F(x) \cdot a = \frac{1}{3}[a_1, a_2, a_3]$$

EDIT2: Continuing with the spherical coordinates. Assuming that:
$$\begin{array}
xx_1 = rsin(\theta)cos(\varphi)\\
x_2 = rsin(\theta)sin(\varphi)\\
x_3 = rcos(\theta)
\end{array}$$
Plugging that in the equation and using pythagorean identity 2 times I get:
$$ \phi(r,\theta,\varphi)= \frac{r^2}{6} - \frac{1}{2}a^2$$
Then doing the same things as above for spherical:
$$\nabla\phi = [\frac{\delta\phi}{\delta r}, \frac{1}{r} \cdot \frac{\delta\phi}{\delta \theta}, \frac {1}{rsin(\theta)} \cdot \frac{\delta\phi}{\delta\varphi}] = [\frac{r}{3}, 0, 0]$$
EDIT3: Deleted the uncorrect Hessian calculation.

Comment: rot($\nabla$) is always zero. For the rest, your easy/stupid idea is the correct one (what else?).

Comment: Be careful that in the post you are using $a$ both as a vector and as a scalar.

Comment: Is the $rot(\nabla\phi(x)) = 0$ a rule or just correct in this case (scalar field)?

Comment: It is zero whenever it makes sense, and that is in the case of a scalar field.

Comment: I did edits with my potential solutions, can you look them up?

Comment: It is correct given the definition that you gave of $\nabla^2$. Be careful though that this is called the Hessian, not the Laplacian which outputs a number, the trace of the Hessian (although unfortunately the notation $\nabla^2$ is used for both).

Comment: One more thing; considering the spherical gradient listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient, I expect the derivative has to be done first, before multiplying with the element in the left (for example: $\frac{1}{r} \frac{\delta f}{\delta\theta}$). I guess it doesn't matter if that means Hessian or Laplacian, as the Hessian "includes" (maybe it's not the right word, I hope you know what I mean) the Laplacian.

Comment: You are correct, the derivative has to be done first. The Hessian contains the information of the Laplacian and more, but it does not mean that "it doesn't matter", they are not the same kind of object.

Comment: Should the value of $\nabla^2\phi$ be the same in both cartesian and spherical coordinates?

Comment: Yes! None of these operators are supposed to be coordinate dependent.

Comment: Then I messed something up, because I don't get the same values. The derivatives on $\theta$ and $\varphi$ have to give $0$, because they are not in the equation, unless I used the spherical coords. wrong.

Comment: Wait, I answered in terms of Laplacian. The Hessian is completely coordinate dependent.

Comment: It still doesn't work either way: if I take my $\frac{r}{3}$ (as the Laplacian) and try to use the inverse (spherical to cartesian) it gives $\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}{3}$.

Comment: $\frac{r}{3}$ is not the Laplacian here, it is the first coordinate of thegradient.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. But continuing from the $grad$ i get $\frac{1}{3}$ as the Laplacian, not $1$ as in the cartesian coordinates (as the Laplacian is the $tr$ of the Hessian). The $\frac{r}{3}$ is indeed the first and the only coordinate of the $grad$ that is not equal to zero, according to my calculations. I'm editing my post when something clarifies here, so watch it as we talk as it can give you insight of what I am currently talking about.

Comment: I'm posting an answer, it's easier there. You simply took the derivative of $r/3$ with respect to $r$, that's not what the Hessian does.

Comment: What's rot?....

Comment: From wikipedia: "$curl$ in vector calculus is a vector operator that describes the infinitesimal `rotation` of a vector field in three-dimensional Euclidean space". That's why it's sometimes refered to as $rot$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like the gradient is not exactly $({\partial\over\partial r}, {\partial\over\partial \theta}, {\partial\over\partial \varphi})$ in spherical coordinates because of the Jacobian that gets into the change of variables, the Hessian is not computed via simple derivations either.

The top-left entry of the Hessian in spherical coordinates is $\frac{1}{r^2}{\partial\over\partial r}(r^2{\partial\phi\over\partial r})$, which does give you the $1$ that you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your help and time. I should be a'ok with the rest now. Indeed it works when I plug it in. As you said, the Laplacian is the same, but the Hessian is different.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, the Hessian is a tricky thing.

Comment: I still got one more question. The gradient in spherical is $[\frac{r}{3}, 0, 0]$ (or is it?). But now when I do the said before conversion to cartesian coordinates, I get $[\frac{\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}}{3}, 0, 0]$. Is the gradient also coordinate dependent? I see that it shouldn't be. Even if I now sum up all the elements in that vector in cartesian i get $\frac{x_1 + x_2 + x_3}{3}$, but here I get the square of the sum of second powers divided by 3.

Comment: That's simply not how you do a conversion to cartesian, you don't just do the change of variables inside the coordinates. You have to realise that in spherical, the first coordinate means something happening along $r$, whereas in cartesian, the first coordinate is along $x_1$, totally unrelated - you shouldn't expect it to work this way.

Comment: Okay, I think I just gotta to sit and think about it from the theory perspective. But still, is the gradient in spherical coordinates correct?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.